# Need a Conditional for Tally

Tags: conditionals

I'm using the [Tally](https://github.com/amphibian/tally.ee_addon) add-on to display a total from a custom field I have that stores numeric values. It's working great, my only problem is that I need a conditional setup that will display 'your current total is 0' or even just '0' when the logged in user has a null or zero tally total.

When a logged in user visits my front-end template, it works perfectly if they have tally but if the tally is null or zero then it's completely blank. Does anyone know how to setup a conditional like this for Tally? I couldn't find any examples of conditionals for Tally in the documentation and I tried the code below to no avail:

```
{if tally:total == ""}You current total is 0.{/if}
```

The code above just displays every time whether or not the logged in user has a tally or not and I've tried it both with nothing in the quotes and with a zero in the quotes. I would greatly appreciate any tips or suggestions for accomplishing this, Thanks!

Comment: You are using this in an embedded template as per the docs yes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I contacted the plugin author about this issue and he gave me the following code:

```
{if '{exp:tally:total collection="hours"}' < 1}Your current total is 0.{/if}
```

This works perfectly and does exactly what I need. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Looking at that plugin's code, it should work fine if you're using a tag pair, and its `{tally_total}` variable, e.g.:

```
{exp:tally:total}
    {if ! tally_total}Your current total is 0.{/if}
{/exp:tally:total}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with Tally but I wonder if [the NOT operator](https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/templates/conditionals.html#logical-operators) could be your friend.

Something like:

```
{if ! tally:total}You current total is 0.{/if}
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply and suggestion. Unfortunately that's not working and generates a parse error.